# Customize Google Call widget size or graphic

Tags: customization, call, voice

Is there a way to customize the size of this widget?  My client wants it in the header but it's too big.

[image: google widget]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://www.google.com/voice/resources/2714463893-style01_full.jpg))</sub>

This is the embed code they offer for a WordPress widget.  There must be a way to cause an onclick of a custom image to trigger this?

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://clients4.google.com/voice/embed/webCallButton" width="230" height="85">
<param name="movie" value="https://clients4.google.com/voice/embed/webCallButton" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="id=#####numberhidden####&style=0" /></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this link which doesn't exactly let you resize it but it's a way to push the variables that Google needs in a custom format through input fields.

http://razvangavril.com/web-development/custom-google-voice-widget/

and

http://razvangavril.com/web-development/custom-google-voice-widget-2/

The `ButID` label for `button_id` part is a *text field* where you enter your **Google Voice ID**.  You can find that in their embed code by looking for `ID=`. I chose to make it a hidden field, and manually insert mine.

The other two fields are your name, and phone number. You then insert their script with the form, customize the look, and you're done.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the tutorial from:

http://razvangavril.com/web-development/custom-google-voice-widget/

You could create a button or image of any kind and have that throw a dialog box with your call form.

Comment: You do realize you just repeated op's answer, right?